# How to find a basis for this $\Bbb R$-vector space : $\{(x, y) \in \Bbb C^2 \mid x + iy = 0\}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I tried this :

$\{(x, y) \in \Bbb C^2 \mid x + iy = 0\} \iff \{(x, y) \in \Bbb C^2 \mid x = -iy\} \iff \{(-iy, y) \in \Bbb C^2\} \iff \{y(-i, 1) \in \Bbb C^2\}$

So a basis for that vector space would be the set composed of one vector : $\{(-i, 1)\}$. But that answer is wrong because apparently, a basis would be $\{(-i, 1), (1, i)\}$.

So my question is : how can I find the basis of such a vector space without doing a mistake like I did ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that $x,y \in \Bbb C $, not $x,y\in \Bbb R$. You have that $x+iy= 0$ implies: $$(x,y) = (-iy,y) = y(-i,1) = (y_1 + iy_2) (-i,1) = y_1(-i,1) + y_2(1,i),$$for $y_1,y_2\in \Bbb R$, whence ${\rm span}_{\Bbb R}(\{(1,i),(-i,1)\}) = \{(x,y) \in \Bbb C^2 \mid x + iy = 0\}$. You showed that this subspace equals ${\rm span}_{\Bbb C}(\{(-i,1)\})$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$
(-iy,y)\in \mathbb{C}^2 
$$
is correct, but with $y \in \mathbb{C}$.

So, $y=a \cdot (1)+b \cdot(i)$ is a linear combination of $1$ and $i$.